# BlueZ hci_* API to make the host discoverable

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, bluez

Environment:

- Linux
- BlueZ Bluetooth stack
- C API
- No usage of the dbus interface

I must say that the HCI BlueZ C API ( [hci_lib.h](http://code.haskell.org/blues/blues/include/hci_lib.h) ) is poorly documented, having that said, Is there a C hci_* API controlling the host discover-able state? something similar to "hci_write_simple_pairing_mode" enabling control of discoverability?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't such an API in the HCI lib. But there definetely is through the [Bluez DBUS adapter API](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/adapter-api.txt). And the HCI lib is really for internal use (even though many people use it). One of the reasons why it isn't better documented I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The following hci command makes the adapter discoverable
   hciconfig hci0 piscan

Following is the corresponding code from hciconfig

```
if (!strcmp(opt, "pscan"))
    dr.dev_opt = SCAN_PAGE;
else if (!strcmp(opt, "piscan"))
     dr.dev_opt = SCAN_PAGE | SCAN_INQUIRY;
if (ioctl(ctl, HCISETSCAN, (unsigned long) &dr) < 0) {
```

Here ctl is what is got from:

```
 if ((ctl = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, BTPROTO_HCI)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be found at [hciconfig.c](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/bluetooth/bluez/tools/hciconfig.c) in specific at 'cmd_scan' implementation ( having opt = "piscan" ), derivation of that follows

```
    HRESULT BluZbridge::SetDiscoverable(IN BOOL bVisible) {
        if (0 == m_fdHCI)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_READY);
        hci_dev_req req = { DEFAULT_HCI_ADAPTER_ID, ((TRUE == bVisible) ? (SCAN_PAGE | SCAN_INQUIRY) : SCAN_DISABLED) };
        if (ioctl(m_fdHCI, HCISETSCAN, (unsigned long)&req) < 0) {
            perror("Can't set scan mode on hci0");
            return HRESULT_GET_ERRNO();
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
```